# Clarifying abbreviation presentation

Tags: abbreviations

Consider the following sentence as an example:

> The present analysis suggests that the central Indian (CI) region is loaded with higher aerosol concentration and that rainfall is significantly negatively correlated with aerosol optical depth (significant at 1 % significance level) over CI.

where the first instance of the abbreviation "CI" is presented as short of "central Indian" and the second instance technically "central India."

Is this an acceptable presentation? Or should I change the second instance to "...over the CI region...."?

Answer (score 1):

It is understood that Central India(CI) is a region. So, you needn't mention it as Central Indian region in the first place.

Instead you could write: " The present analysis suggests that Central India(CI) is loaded...  "

Comment: I'm not writing; I'm editing. I could do the change you suggested, but the writing identity of the author would be gone. We don't want that.

Comment: In that case it is acceptable to use just "CI". No changes are necessary.

Comment: ayt.. noted bro....